# Using WolframAlpha, in matrix multiplication, why are "squared" and ^2 giving me different results?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, wolframalpha

**"squared" input:** `{{0,1,0,0},{0.325,0,0.2875,0.3875},{0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0}} squared`

**output:**

[image]

**"^2" input:** `{{0,1,0,0},{0.325,0,0.2875,0.3875},{0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0}} ^2`

**output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `squared` operation simply squares all matrix elements.
(`cubed` works in a similar way)

Example:

[image]

The `^2` operation performs a matrix multiplication as expected.

Comment: Thank you. If I may ask, why was this question downvoted? I did not find it anywhere else in SO and followed the guidelines.

Comment: I don't know the reason for the downvote. Perhaps, the question is not directly related to programming, or the downvoter assumed that more own efforts could have answered the question.